# Using useEffect() hook to test a function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm learning Jest basically, I have to write a test case for the useEffect() hook which renders based on a flag[counter], and which internally checks if a localStorage value is present for a field.

```
function sample(props) {
  const counter = props;
  const [displayIcon, setDisplayIcon] = useState(counter);

  function isLocalstoragePresent() {    
    return localStorage.getItem("some_Id");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLocalstoragePresent()) {
      setDisplayIcon(true);
    } else {
      setDisplayIcon(false);
    }
  }, [counter]);

 export default sample;
```

Can some one help me in writing test case/provide a guidence for the UseEffect which internally calls isLocalstoragePresent() method aswell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot run tests of function or variables within a class/function. only if you isolate them can you test them in isolation.

Comment: Joe Lloyd, thanks for the reply, can you please suggest me the changes I can do for the above code?

Comment: move `isLocalstoragePresent` outside the function. and run a test with that if you like. then run a shallow test where you mock the return or `isLocalstoragePresent` with a positive result and negative result. You cannot get the value of counter unless you spy and mock useState, that's a little more complex.

Comment: ok, thank you.. will try that approach, then testing useEffect() will be simpler I think.

Comment: yeah thats important, write code thats ez to test. it really simplifies all your code

Comment: I seperated out this code 
function isLocalstoragePresent() {    
    return localStorage.getItem("some_Id");
  }
and wrote the below testcase, 
  it("check if the isLocalstoragePresent is called", () => {
  const isLocalstoragePresent = jest.fn();
  expect(isLocalstoragePresent).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
still its failing, I tried mockImplementation instead of jest.fn() as well, still I'm getting the error I mentioned, am I doing something wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: yeah you need to spy and mock with jest.fn and then see that its been called. make sure you import it as well to both the component and to the test because you cannot test spy if the function is in the same file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the unit test solution using `jestjs` and `react-dom/test-utils`:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function sample(props) {
  const { counter } = props;
  const [displayIcon, setDisplayIcon] = useState(counter);

  function isLocalstoragePresent() {
    return localStorage.getItem('some_Id');
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLocalstoragePresent()) {
      setDisplayIcon(true);
    } else {
      setDisplayIcon(false);
    }
  }, [counter]);

  return <div>{displayIcon ? 'icon' : ''}</div>;
}

export default sample;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import Sample from './';
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('60639673', () => {
  let container;
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
  });

  it('should display icon', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(localStorage.__proto__, 'getItem').mockReturnValueOnce('1');
    const mProps = { counter: false };
    await act(async () => {
      render(<Sample {...mProps}></Sample>, container);
    });
    expect(container.querySelector('div').textContent).toBe('icon');
    expect(localStorage.__proto__.getItem).toBeCalledWith('some_Id');
    localStorage.__proto__.getItem.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should not display icon', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(localStorage.__proto__, 'getItem').mockReturnValueOnce('');
    const mProps = { counter: true };
    await act(async () => {
      render(<Sample {...mProps}></Sample>, container);
    });
    expect(container.querySelector('div').textContent).toBe('');
    expect(localStorage.__proto__.getItem).toBeCalledWith('some_Id');
    localStorage.__proto__.getItem.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60639673/index.test.tsx (9.723s)
  60639673
    ✓ should display icon (41ms)
    ✓ should not display icon (8ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.242s
```

Dependencies versions:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"jest": "^25.1.0"
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60639673