# Test useEffect hook which has an aync method call within it

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Presently using `useEffect` to call customMethod which is an async method that I have written

in another js file.

How could I test this, possibly via `jest`? And since the calls to `useState` is in there too,

presumably they would fall under the same test too.

Seen other examples like the following. But most are either using `react testing library`

or not testing `useEffect` similar to mine. where it is calling another async method which is not external like fetch

but an internal method within own project.

[Using useEffect() hook to test a function in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639673/using-useeffect-hook-to-test-a-function-in-jest)

[Trigger useEffect in Jest testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147444/trigger-useeffect-in-jest-testing)

https://epicreact.dev/how-to-test-react-use-effect/

Could I get some guidance on how to test this pls.

My functional component.

```
const MyFunc = ({
    myparams
}) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const tempMethod = async => {
            return await customMethod();
        }

        tempMethod()
            .then(r => setData(r))
            .catch(() => setData(false));

    }, []);

    // ... other logic

    return (
        <SomeComponent/>
    );
}
```